# When I run my switch case and choose an option, it will continuously loop that option

Tags: java, loops, calculator

My goal is to ask the user to enter an operation, it will be calculated from another class that does a basic calculation, then It will take the result, and ask the user to choose an operation again, and continue with the same number. Or choose C and clear the number to 0

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalculatorClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to calculator\n You will be able to use this program to add, subtract, multiply, and divide values!\n");
        double number1;
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        number1 = keyboard.nextDouble();
        Calculator obj1 = new Calculator(number1);
        keyboard.nextLine();

        // System.out.println("Please enter an operation ( + , - , / , *) :");
        // input=keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter an operation ( + , - , / , *) :");
        String input = keyboard.nextLine();;
```

I'm not sure why but this while loop, which I am using to test the operator input, isn't working when I run it.

```
        while  (!"+".equals(input) || !"-".equals(input) || !"/".equals(input) || !"*".equals(input)) {
                System.out.println("That is not a valid operation, please enter an operation ( + , - , / , *) :");
                input = keyboard.nextLine();
        }    



        int counter=0;    
        Loopy:
        while(counter<1)

        {
            switch (input) {
                case "+": {
                    int add;
                    System.out.println("Enter a second number to add: ");
                    add = keyboard.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("\nThe sum is: ");
                    System.out.println("The nubmer is now ");
                    System.out.println(obj1.getNumber());
                    System.out.println(obj1.add(add));
                    number1 = obj1.getNumber();
                    break;
                }   
                case "-": {
                    int subtract;
                    System.out.println("Enter a second number to subtract: ");
                    subtract = keyboard.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("\nThe difference is: ");
                    System.out.println(obj1.subtract(subtract));
                    System.out.println("The nubmer is now ");
                    System.out.println(obj1.getNumber());
                    number1 = obj1.getNumber();
                    break;
                }
                case "/": {
                    int div;
                    System.out.println("Enter a second number to divide");
                    div = keyboard.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("\nThe quotient is: ");
                    System.out.println(obj1.divide(div));
                    System.out.println("The nubmer is now ");
                    System.out.println(obj1.getNumber());
                    number1 = obj1.getNumber();
                    break;
                }
                case "*": {
                    int times;
                    System.out.println("Enter a second nubmer to multiply");
                    times = keyboard.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("\nThe product is: ");
                    System.out.println("The nubmer is now ");
                    System.out.println(obj1.getNumber());
                    System.out.println(obj1.multiply(times));
                    number1 = obj1.getNumber();
                    break;
                }
                case "C": {
                    obj1.setNumber(number1);
                    System.out.println("The nubmer is now ");
                    System.out.println(obj1.getNumber());
                    break;

                }
            }

        counter--;
```

This println ends up printing twice for some reason

`````
        System.out.println("\nPlease enter an operation ( + , - , / , *) :");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();
        continue;
        }
    }
}

````

Here is my calculator program (My instruction is to make it on a separate file
````
public class Calculator
{
    private double number;

    Calculator(double x){number=x;}
    Calculator(){}

    public void setNumber(double x){number=x;}
    public double getNumber(){return number;}



            public double add(double a){
                number+=a;
                return (number);
            } 
            public double subtract(double a){
                number-=a;
                return (number);
            }

            public double multiply(double a){
                number*=a;
                return (number);
            }

            public double divide(double a){
                number/=a;
                return (number);
            }
}
`````

Comment: If it stops, try putting in another number into your console.

Comment: It seems to just keep on saying (for example when my case is "/") "Enter a second number to divide" over and over again, it never seems to reach the break, so I can reset it.

Comment: Could you edit your post to make it readable? Right now, it seems that the switch is outside the while loop

Comment: @EricHubbard Okay, then please add your **input** into your question. Additionally, what is the **Calculator** obj1? What is this calculator? Please add the code of the calculator class into your question. I'd like to be able to personally run your program, to see potential flaws.

Comment: You assign a value to input outside of the while loop and then only change it when it fails if() test which it never does..

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue in in below lines :
int counter=0;
        Loopy:
        while(counter<1)
** your logic for methods
**and at end --
counter--;

so counter is always less than 1 and hence always in loop